# Angular 2 loads HTTP request 5 times even though i am calling only once

Tags: http, angular, angular2-services

For example:

```
ngOnInit() 
    {
        this.user = new User();
        this.result = new Result();
         this.route.params
          .switchMap((params: Params) => this.user.id = params['id'])
          .subscribe((user: User) => this.getUser());
     }
    getUser()
        {
            this.result.updateInfo("getting records...")
            this.user.id = this.user.id.toLowerCase();
          this._serivce.getUser(this.user.id).subscribe(userobj => 
            {
                this.user = userobj;
                console.log(userobj);//five times
            },error => this.result.updateError(error));

        }
```

the useronj gets printed five times in console.
Service:

```
getUser(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(<url>, { headers: this.headers })
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Update: Only the ngOnInit calls getUser, that too only once!

Comment: It depends of which methods call getUser(). You should post the whole code of the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are using `switchMap`? You are also doing a lot of subscribing there, which could cause the issue. What you are trying to achieve, which seems to be getting a user by the id parameter, so this should do the trick:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params
     .subscribe(params => {
         let id = params['id'];
         this._service.getUser(id.toLowerCase())
           .subscribe(userobj => {
              console.log(userObj);
         }); 
      });
}
```

**EDIT**: As a sidenote, per comment from OP (since comments tend to go unnoticed) Turned out that `switchMap` was the sole issue in this case. So my suspicion that all the subscribing could be an additional cause for this issue, turned out to not be true :)

Comment: Thank you. It stopped loading the user five times. And thank you for pointing SwitchMap, that was the issue. Rest all the methods, I have left it as it is. Because they are being used in the other methods.

Comment: Yeah okay, I understand. I tried a similar setup with switchmap, for me it caused 8 updates :D But yeah, good that it was figured out :)